# Play framework (Java) model validation - different check for create() and update()

Tags: java, validation, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm using Play 2.3.7 and I basically have the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387931/different-model-validation-on-user-name-in-scala-play-2-form-mapping-in-create) but I am using Java and I don't know Scala.

In my case I have a `CSVData` class with a `name` attribute that I want to be unique. In my controller actions for both `create()` and `update(Long id)` I bind a form to this class with

```
Form<CSVData> formData = Form.form(CSVData.class).bindFromRequest();
```

As explained in the [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaForms), the `validate()` function gets called on `bindFromRequest()`. Here's my current validate function:

```
public List<ValidationError> validate() {

    List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();

    // Unique validation on name
    if(CSVData.find.where().eq("name", getName()).findRowCount() != 0) {
        errors.add(new ValidationError("name", "Name must be unique. That value is already taken."));
    }

    // other stuff

}
```

Clearly the issue with my current solution is the fact that when `update()` gets called, there already is a row in the DB with that name. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17391856/1092403) suggests checking the `id` attribute of the object in the controller action, and then provides a Scala code snippet, but that example contained a User class, and my application does not. How can I can check if the object in the database with the matching `name` is the same one that I am currently updating? Should I check for this in the `validate()` function or in my controller?

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906096/play-framework-2-3-how-to-add-unique-constraint-to-sample-application) for a solution to how I checked uniqueness, which was the underlying problem I was facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to perform different validations for `create()` and `update()` in the `validate()` function in the model, but you can perform the validations in the respective controller actions, like so

```
public static Result create() {

    Form<CSVData> formData = Form.form(CSVData.class).bindFromRequest();

}    

public static Result update() {

    Form<CSVData> formData = Form.form(CSVData.class).bindFromRequest();

    if( !formData.hasErrors() ){
        if(formData.field("name").value().equals( .... ) {
            // do some check here
            // add ValidationError if needed
        }
    }

}
```

I had not considered performing the validations directly in the controller before, but this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Create two separate classes one for `insert()` - `InsertCsvData` and one for `updated()` - `UpdateCsvData` with two different `validate()` implementations. Optionally, create base class for storing common properties/behaviours.

Comment: I suppose that could work but I would prefer a cleaner solution. Also, let's say the base class is `CSVData`, then in my view template I would like to pass in `@(csvForm: Form[CSVData])`. However I get a compile error for type mismatch `Note: models.InsertCSVData <: models.CSVData, but Java-defined class Form is invariant in type T.` How would I change the scala view templates to accept a form of the type of the base class?

Comment: Use scala generics: `@(csvForm: Form[_ <: CSVData])`

Comment: I realized that this still does not completely solve my problem. What should I check for in the `validate()` function of the `UpdateCsvData` class?