# Play Framework 2.3 How to add unique constraint to sample application

Tags: forms, playframework, playframework-2.3

Given the [Play Framework 2.3 Computer Database sample application](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.3.x/samples/java/computer-database), I would like to practice adding a unique constraint on an attribute. Let's say I want the `name` attribute of the `Computer` class to be unique. I've tried to do this by adding a `validate()` function (and a getter) to `Computer.java`:

```
public List<ValidationError> validate() {

    List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();

    if(Computer.find.where().eq("name", getName()).findRowCount() != 0){
        errors.add(new ValidationError("name", "Name must be unique. That value is already taken."));
    }

    return errors;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

This check works when creating new records in the database, however, this now causes a validation error when you **update** a Computer object but don't change the name. Is there a way to add a [uniqueness constraint, similar to Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)? How can I validate uniqueness in Play?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: see the [answer by davide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28913174/1092403).

I ended up using the `@Column(unique = true)` constraint from the javax.persistence API. This doesn't generate an error in Play forms; instead, it throws a `PersistenceException`. Therefore I had to add change my controller to achieve the behavior I wanted. Both the `create()` and `update()` actions need a try/catch like this:

```
 try {
     computerForm.get().save();
 } catch (PersistenceException pe) {
     flash("error", "Please correct errors below.");
     formData.reject("name", "Name conflict. Please choose a different name.");
     return badRequest(createForm.render(computerForm));
 }
```

**UPDATE 2**: each of the answers below is a possible solution

Comment: `PersistenceException` is too broad for this IMHO, but it's your choice

Comment: @biesior that's a good point. I suppose it's not the best solution. Would you suggest catching a different exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude current entity from unique checking, i.e. like that:

```
if(Computer.find.where().eq("name", getName()).ne("id", getId()).findRowCount() != 0){
     errors.add(new ValidationError("name", "Name must be unique."));
}
```

It will give you SQL query during update:

```
select count(*) from computer t0 where t0.name = 'Foo' and t0.id <> 123
```

And this during create:

```
select count(*) from computer t0 where t0.name = 'Foo' and t0.id is not null
```

**P.S.** `ne()` expression stands for *Not Equal To* and of course this approach assumes that your `name` field is `Required`

**Edit:** I sent you pull request with working solution, all you need is to add hidden field in your `editForm` like:

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" value='@computerForm("id").value'/>
```

Other thing is that you can simplify your model, i.e. don't need for getters for public fields.

Comment: I tried that, and the problem is that even on an update, the data that is binded from the request doesn't yet have an `id`, therefore `getId()` is always null in this `if` statement. Try putting this line before the `if` and you will see what I am talking about: `Logger.debug("current id: " + getId());`

Comment: As usually I tested the approach (on other project NOT Computer sample) before posting this answer and it was ok. Publish it somewhere (i.e. temporary Github repo) so I can check what's wrong.

Comment: Check the edit and pull the request, one small change makes it working

Answer (score 2):

I not sure if this answer your question, because I'm not familiar with Ruby syntax.

To "create a uniqueness constraint in the database" you can use the [javax persistence API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html). Ebean will also recognize this.

To have a plain uniqueness constraint which involves a single field, you can use the [`@Column` annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#unique%28%29):

```
  @Entity
  public class Computer extends Model {
    ...

    @Column(unique = true)
    public String name;

    ...
  }
```

If you need some combination of fields to be unique, instead use the 
[`@Table` annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Table.html#uniqueConstraints%28%29)

```
  @Table(
        uniqueConstraints=
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"name", "brand"})
    )
  @Entity
  public class Computer extends Model {
    ...

    public String name;
    public String brand;

    ...
  }
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Yes I already tried putting the `@Column(unique = true)`, however this throws an error at the database level, and doesn't generate a validation error when filling out the Play form, which is what I need.

Comment: What I usually do is to wrap the save or update in a try-catch block, to catch the exception raised and then I redirected back to the form, using the flash scope to signal the error